# Is there any terminology called "hypochecking" in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, function, macros

I just came across below question on Internet:

> Macros and function are related in what aspect?
>
> (a)recursion
>
> (b)varying no of arguments
>
> (c)hypochecking
>
> (d)type declaration"

I am ruling out the option d cause macros just do argument substitution. Option a is not applicable to macros.

I am weighing between option b and c.
Both functions and macros can have varying number of arguments.
So my gut feeling is answer is option b unless there is something called "hypochecking".

Can you please confirm. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it's meant to be "typo checking", and therefore a self-referential joke.

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth: so in that case are you suggesting the answer could be both option b and c?

Comment: This is an interview question. Perhaps *hypocheck* is a made-up word to determine if you know your framistat from your whizjam.

Comment: Its "type checking" and it applies when you are trying to differentiate between macros vs functions.The latter provide type checking for function arguments while former does not.

Comment: @Rob : Thanks Rob. Agree with your point.

Comment: @Als - Are you saying that "hypocheck" is a typographic error and the author meant to say "type checking"? Or, are you saying that the word "hypocheck" exists and means "type checking?"

Comment: @Robᵩ: The former.There is no word as "hypocheck" unless there is a vet checking a "hypopotammus" that wont figure in c++ though So the former, Yes.

Comment: Maybe it was messed up during OCR?

Comment: The question itself is ambiguous and nonsensical. I have a feeling the person who posed it does not speak English.

Comment: The questions are easily found searching for "hypochecking". Most of them are either weird or plain wrong. Don't pay any attention to those questions *or* their "answers". It may be harmful to expose yourself to them for extended periods of time.

Comment: The question comes from http://www.indiabix.com/placement-papers/hcl/3511  (#11).

Comment: Not that it's the answer to (c), but consider this: Many programmers do not validate input when they should — if Latin were to be used (partway) for it, you could name it “hypochecking”.

Comment: @abelenky: eeugh.  There is a scary amount of *just-plain-wrong* out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Is there any terminology called “hypochecking” in C/C++?*"

**NO**